# .NET Core compression does not work in my controller

Tags: asp.net-core

I just created a new .NET Core 3.1 Web API project based by the template in VS 2019, and I added code following the official example in `startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression();
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

but the compression middleware does not work

[webapi response in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbgr6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net Core Response Compression is disabled by default for HTTPS traffic, which it appears you are using.  Try changing your call to AddResponseCompression() to turn it on for https.

```
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.EnableForHttps = true;
        });
```

You can see the MS docs for use of response compression with https, as there are security implications noted in the article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1#compression-with-secure-protocol